# How to add the chart name immediately after the chart is created in vba?

Tags: excel, vba, graph, charts

This is just a part of the code.

```
For i = 1 To Total_Graphs
    Sheet3.Select
    Num_Variables = Sheet2.Range("Num_Variables").Offset(i - 1, 0).Value
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
    ActiveChart.ChartType = xlLine
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Sheet1.Range(Total_Variable_Range(i))
    For j = 1 To Num_Variables
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(j).Name = Sheet2.Range("List_format").Offset(i - 1, j - 1).Value
    Next j
Next i
```

Now, i want to name the chart created myself, instead of excel giving the name automatically.

Comment: Also, can anyone help with proper structuring of the code. Thanks

Comment: I tried that. Getting a Runtime Error '-2147024882 (8007000e)'

Comment: hm.. shapes(index).Name = "new name"?

Comment: Since I don't know what name excel will give it, what index should I write.

Comment: the last one like `shapes.count`?

Comment: Thanks for the discussion. I figured it out because of this.

Answer (score 0):

For the naming, the `AddChart` method returns the `Shape` so you can set a variable this and work with it...

```
Dim s As Shape
Set s = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart
s.Select
s.Name = "some name"
```

Comment: [Avoid using select](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros)...so probably `ws.Shapes(ws.Shapes.Count).Name = "new name"`